# What is wrong with this code? I'm new to c++!

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;



class UserBase{
public:
    void GetUsername(string GetName){
        MyUserName = GetName;


    }
    void GetPassword(string GetPassword){
        GetPassword = MyPassword;


    }

private:
    string MyUserName;
    string MyPassword;

};



int main(){
    UserBase Input;
    string MyName;
    string MyPassword;
    Input.GetUsername("test");
    Input.GetPassword("noob");
    cout << "enter your username, please." << endl;
    cin >> MyName;
    if (MyName == Input.GetUsername){
        cout << "enter your password.." << endl;
        cin >> MyPassword;
        if (MyPassword == Input.GetPassword){
            cout << "login was successfull" << endl;
            Sleep(5000);
        }

    }


    return 0; // if 0 then its a success
}
```

//so basically im trying to make a username and login password application. i am new to c++, i have only coded for 3 weeks and im just toying around. whenever i try to run it says that there were erros, but it didnt show me where and no red whatsoever.i use vs 2013.

Comment: First off your get properties don't actually return value. In terms of usufulnes both do basically nothing. On top of that you are trying to compare `string` to pointer to method.

Answer (score 0):

here, I corrected it. Lot's of mistakes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;



class UserBase{
public:
    string GetUsername(){
        return MyUserName;
    }
    string GetPassword(){
        return MyPassword;
    }
    void setUsername(string name){
        MyUserName = name;
    }
    void setPassword(string password){
        MyPassword = password;
    }

private:
    string MyUserName;
    string MyPassword;

};



int main(){
    UserBase Input;
    string MyName;
    string MyPassword;
    Input.setUsername("test");
    Input.setPassword("noob");
    cout << "enter your username, please." << endl;
    cin >> MyName;
    if (MyName == Input.GetUsername()){
        cout << "enter your password.." << endl;
        cin >> MyPassword;
        if (MyPassword == Input.GetPassword()){
            cout << "login was successfull" << endl;
            Sleep(5000);
        }

    }


    return 0; // if 0 then its a success
}
```

you had no real getPassword, getUsername, you only had setters (wich are called get... wich is confusing !!). You also called "getPassword" (in wrong context) with wrong syntax.

```
getPassword; //wrong
getPassword(); //correct
```

Comment: Won't work, since there is no `UserBase::GetUsername()`, signature won't match `UserBase::GetUsername(std::string)`

Comment: It might compile now, but still won't work since `MyUserName` and `MyPassword` are uninitialized.

Comment: I wouldn't know, leaving decision if it's what he wanted to OP.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
if (MyName == Input.GetUsername)
```

But `GetUsername` is not a valid method call firstly, and anyways, `GetUsername()` returns `void`, where you're expecting to compare to a string `MyName`. Also, because the two strings within the class are private access, you don't have a way of accessing them at all outside of the class, in your main function. If you added a getter method like `string getUsername() const` which returned the correct string inside, then you could compare to this.